# Retrieve about 100 000 of records from BigQuery or Datastore

Tags: google-bigquery, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-datastore

We would like to cache some data on Google Compute Engine (about 100 000 rows of data). Each row has 3-4 columns. Would you recommend to load this data from Google Cloud Datastore or BigQuery?

BigQuery does the job of "creating" this data. However, we are not sure it is a good practice to read a medium amount of data from it remotely.

Answer (score 1):

[BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/) is really focused on analytical queries (ie, `SELECT user_agent, SUM(request_cost) FROM my_table_of_requests WHERE user_agent != NULL GROUP BY user_agent`) rather than exporting 100s of thousands of rows.

[Datastore](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/) is focused on application-level data retrieval (ie, "get these exact rows") rather than analytical queries, but it provides secondary indexing (aka, filtering) as well as other fancy OLTP things (like ACID transactions, automatic data replication, etc). For your 100k rows, you'll be paying $0.06 just to retrieve them all once.

If you just want to dump 100k rows of data into something, and then read it back (without any filtering on the server side, or need for transactions or replication), neither of these seem like the right choice. You might want to consider just storing a CSV output file of the data in [Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/) and calling it a day.

If you do need advanced querying, transactions, etc, Datastore will get the job done, but might be more costly than you'd expect. You might want to consider loading this data into a SQL database (ie, PostgreSQL or MySQL) which should easily handle 100k rows.